# Getting error using FirebaseUser - says deprecated

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am a beginner in `Flutter` and i am trying to integrate `Firebase` with Flutter for the first time. I got several errors, cleared them one by one but this final one is where im stuck. I am actually trying for email/password authentication. Could you please help

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'dart:async';

final FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
class login extends StatefulWidget{
@override
_loginState createState()=>_loginState();
}

class _loginState extends State<login>{
final _formKey= GlobalKey<FormState>();

TextEditingController emailController = new TextEditingController();
TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();

//String email='';
//String password='';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar( // multiple properties separated by ,
      title:Text('Login',
      style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black )
      ),
      actions:<Widget>[
        FlatButton.icon(onPressed:(){
        Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/signup');
        }
        , icon:Icon(Icons.people), label:Text('Register')),
      ],
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[200],
      centerTitle:true,
      
    ),
    // actions used for multiple widgets
    body:Center(
      child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
      child: Form(
        key:_formKey,
        child: Column(
        children:<Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          controller: emailController,
          validator:(val)=>val.isEmpty?'Enter Email' :null,
          autocorrect: true,
            autofocus: false,
            cursorColor: Colors.blue,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Email Address',
              icon: new Icon(
                Icons.people,
              )
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            onChanged:(val){
              //email = val;
            },
            
        ),
        SizedBox(height:10.0),
        TextFormField(
          controller: passwordController,
          validator:(val)=>val.length < 6 ?'Enter Password: Length greater than 6' :null,
          autocorrect:true,
            autofocus: false,
            cursorColor: Colors.blue,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Password',
              icon: new Icon(
                Icons.mail,
              )
              ),
            obscureText: true,
            onChanged:(val){
             // password=val;
            },
            
        ),
        SizedBox(height:10.0),
        RaisedButton(onPressed:(){
          if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){ 
          Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/page1_menu');
          }
          else{return null;}
        },
        child: Text('Login'),
        color: Colors.blueAccent[400],
        )
        ]
      )
      ),
    )

  ),
 );
}
void signUpWithEmailPassword()
async {
  FirebaseUser user;
  user = await mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text);


}
}
```

[image: error]

The error reads as follows : A value of type 'UserCredential' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseUser'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'FirebaseUser'.dartinvalid_assignment

Answer (score 1):

```
UserCredential userCredential = await mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text);
```

try like this.

Answer (score 1):

Deprecated means it was used available before in the previous versions, but now it's no longer supported. In this case, they have deprecated the FirebaseUser class. So instead you have to use the UserCredential class.

```
void signUpWithEmailPassword()
async {
  UserCredential user;
  user = await mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text);
}
```